# Laptop Screen worked and now is blank on boot up/BIOS/POST

Tags: windows, windows-8, laptop, display, lcd

My laptop booted up fine however after I did a reboot now I do not see a POST or BIOS at all on a bootup. There is also no beeps and I hear the fans. The screen remains blank the entire time.

I checked the wire connections and they seem perfectly ok. Nothing has come detached.

What else can I try and what would cause this?

Someone once said you could heat the board up and it would reset the sockets.

Comment: To eliminate the display being faulty , connect your laptop's HDMI port or VGA port to an external screen , then boot it , if there is display on this 2nd screen then your graphics / screen are fine , otherwise  its a Pre-Bios fault and you need to investigate more , could be : motherboard , cpu ,ram..., you didn't mention what's the model of your laptop ?

Comment: I tried plugging in an HDMI connection and I get nothing on the external screen. The monitor knows there is a connection however.

Comment: There is a combination to switch between the internal and the external screen , consult your laptop's manual.

Comment: Hey, I tried doing that with the key combo, but because the system does not boot to the OS I am under the assumption that the key combo does not work

Comment: Possibly you have  graphics fault , nothing much that can be done in such case except for replacing the motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

Blank screen at post sometimes is a memory problem. Try reseating, or boot with one chip to see if that helps. (if you have two chips) I saw this happen and there was a burned/discolored spot on a memory chip.

Comment: Even if it booted up perfectly only to on a ctrl+alt+del a moment later display nothing? However, I did try RAM reset nothing.